# DC-DC converter grounding

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have no idea should I connect Vin(-) input pin to COM output pin in this converter. Both pins are somehow grounds. The converter works in both cases, but what is the proper way?

[image: dcdc]

Answer (score 3):

No don't use COM. That is the common midrail (aka 0 volt) reference for the isolated output voltages +Vout and -Vout. The input voltage is applied between Vin+ and Vin-.

> *but what is the proper way?*

Having said all that, it won't hurt the module to make the connection between COM and Vin- but, you won't have circuit isolation anymore and that's one significant reason why you might have chosen this module: -

[image]

Comment: So i can treat not connecting Vin- with COM as a module feature. I will do this. Thanks!

Comment: It's an isolating DC-to-DC converter so not having the connection is its main feature.

Comment: @cubix if you don't care about the isolation there are other cheaper modules that will do the same thing without isolation.